# Restful webservice with Spring

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I'm trying to learn how to build a restful webservice with Spring on tomcat external server but I'm only able to find guides that use spring-boot. I'd like to fully understand all the lifecycle, is there anyone who can help me to build a simple rest webservice from the scratch?

Answer (score 1):

Are you offline when you do google search? :) just search the term "Spring Rest" see -> [Spring Rest](https://www.google.com.ph/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enPH742PH742&ei=-BEUWs6OBIa00gSoxbKwBw&q=spring%20rest&oq=spring%20rest&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1j0l9.7075.7377.0.7828.4.4.0.0.0.0.119.119.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.1.119....0.x1f4oaOxT4c)

And the first 10-20 results are all Spring boot and Rest guides.

Answer (score 0):

yes with the help of spring boot to develop API is very easy. there is not any configuration required. for details please find the below post and I hope you will get answer of all your query.

https://kpblogs.com/java/spring/how-to-build-rest-web-servicesapi-using-spring-framework/